# Is it possible to know the cell of the data of selected item in an active combobox?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use an ActiveX combobox in an excel sheet.

To populate the combobox, I use a range of cells with the items to so.

When I select an item in the combobox, I would like to know the cell that correspond to the selected item.

For example, if I have in cell `J12` the value "Verdadero" and in the cell `J13` the value "False", if I select the intem Verdadero, I would like  to know in code that the cell is `J12`.

How can I achieve that in Excel VBA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ListIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/listindex-property) property of the `ComboBox` and use that value to look to `Offset` the range given by the [`ListFillRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.listfillrange) property of the `ComboBox`.

In the event handler for that combobox (e.g. on Sheet1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim strSelected As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim rngSourceCell As Range
    Dim strSourceCell As String
    
    strSelected = Me.ComboBox1.SelText
    lngIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex                           ' <-- the 0-based index of the selection
    Set rngList = Application.Range(Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange) ' <-- the range you attached to the ComboBox
    Set rngSourceCell = rngList.Cells(1, 1).Offset(lngIndex, 0) ' <-- the cell holding the selected value
    strSourceCell = rngSourceCell.Address(False, False, xlA1, True, False) ' <-- address of that cell
    
    MsgBox strSelected & " from cell " & strSourceCell
    
End Sub
```

[image]